# bootstrap-sass tables - how to generate a single row that spans whole table width to display message when table empty (along with column headings)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a table I have generated and converted to look like bootstraps styles using the supported htlm and css elements.

I have included in my code (Rails 3.2.3) the unless command to display the table rows when data is present, but to display a message in what I hope to be a single row (spanning all columns) when no data is present.

Currently it displays but not as a single row.

I have tried using span, and colspan in the table but cannot get it to look 'clean'

Here is the empty table

[image: Figure 1: table as currently displaying (empty)]

Here is the table with data

[image: Figure 2: table with 1 record]

Here is the code used to generate the table.

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="span10">
    <h1>Listing people</h1>
    <div class="contextual">
      <%= link_to(new_person_path, class: "btn btn-success") do %>
        New Person <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="1">Full Name</th>
    <th colspan="1">DOB</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sex</th>
    <th colspan="1">Address</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody
  <tr>
  <% unless @people.empty? %>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
      <td><%= person.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to person.full_name, person %></td>
      <td><%= person.dob %></td>
      <td><%= person.gender_to_s %></td>
      <td>
        <% person.addresses.each do |f| %>
          <%= f.full_address %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td><%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_person_path(person) %> 
        <%= link_to(edit_person_path(person), class: "btn btn-small") do %>
          Edit <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
        <% end %>

        <!-- This currently works but smells -->
        <%= link_to(person, class: "btn btn-small btn-danger", confirm: t_deletion_confirm(person, person.full_name), method: :delete, :title => t('EHM-G.destroy')) do %>
          Destroy <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  <tr>
  <% else %>
    <td>Move along nothing to see here<td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
</tbody>                                        
</table>

<br />

<%#= link_to 'New Person', new_person_path %>
<%= link_to(new_person_path, class: "btn btn-success") do %>
  New Person <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
</div>
```

So how do I get the message "Move along nothing to see here" (Credit to Github) to "span" the entire width of the row and for the existing headings to look pretty?

Thanks

P.S. The buttons are grey as the scaffolding.css.scss seems to override bootstrap-sass. When the scaffold file is deleted it reverts to normal service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured it out, but there was something wrong (maybe a hidden figure, or rogue space) somewhere in the code as re-coding has corrected it.

Here is what the code looks like now. Does anybody know an easy way to work out what caused it?

```
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Listing people</h1>

  <div class="contextual">
    <%= link_to(new_person_path, class: "btn btn-success") do %>
      New Person <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th colspan="1"></th>
  <th colspan="1">Full Name</th>
  <th colspan="1">DOB</th>
  <th colspan="1">Sex</th>
  <th colspan="1">Address</th>
  <th colspan="1">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% unless @people.empty? %>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= link_to person.full_name, person %></td>
        <td><%= person.dob %></td>
        <td><%= person.gender_to_s %></td>
        <td>
          <% person.addresses.each do |address| %>
            <%= address.full_address %>
          <% end %>
        </td>          
        <td>
          <%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_person_path(person) %> 
          <%= link_to(edit_person_path(person), class: "btn btn-small") do %>
            Edit <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
          <% end %>

          <!-- This currently works but smells -->
          <%= link_to(person, class: "btn btn-small btn-danger", confirm: t_deletion_confirm(person, person.full_name), method: :delete, :title => t('EHM-G.destroy')) do %>
            Destroy <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <% end %>

          <%#= icon_delete_link_to(person, people_path, person.full_name) %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="0">Nothing to see here move along please</td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[image]

While I could not see this yesterday - "wood for trees syndrome!" I hope this might help out someone else.

For my own learning whats the best way to figure out what caused it? To me the code still looks the same

Answer (score 1):

Using diff. E.g., http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/0.9.97/

[image: diff]